# java library vs android library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

what are the differences between Java library and android library and what advantages/disadvantages has each?

Comment: By "java library" and "android library", do you mean eclipse project types?

Comment: yes, this is what I wanted to say

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can include standard Java .jar file libraries in an Android app. They are translated into Dalvik format at .apk build time.

There is an Android Library system which allows the use of shared resources such as layouts and localized strings. As that has more restrictions that regular Java libraries I'd only recommend this method if you actually need to share resources.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: thanks, I must have skipped over this when reading the guide and google wasn't helping to explain this. "is library" was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you meant the android API (or SDK, I can't say) and java API (or SDK). Basically, android is based on java. It is a subset of it, but also adds specific classes and methods to interact with the hardware and the android OS, implement UI, etc.

You can find info about the android architecture here: http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

Concerning advantages/disadvantages, well, if you're developing for the android operating system, then is a great advantage to use the android API. If you're developing for PCs, then part of the android API won't be supported, which is what I would call a disadvantage...

In sum, you need to choose whether to use the andoid API or not depending on what will you be coding: will the API be supported by the OS? Is there a JVM for it?

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know that serialization of classes shared between the two is supported. But they must be located in a package with the same name in both projects.